# ListView con CheckBox Juntos Pero Independientes

Tags: java, android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Todo esto es simplemente un ListView con un Checkbox**
Lo que deseo lograr es que al presionar el primer elemento de la lista en este caso es 'English' no se presione el checkbox y cuando SOLO presione el Checkbox se marque la casilla

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 //Arraylist para guardar los elementos selecionados
 ArrayList<String> selectedItems = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView chl = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.checkable_list);
    chl.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    String[] items = {"English","French","Chinese","Khmer"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.rowlayout,R.id.txt_lan,items);
    chl.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Al presionar un item
    chl.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


        }
    });
}


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución, crear un [ListView Personalizado](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial) lo que podra modificar el diseño a su gusto y agregar todo tipo de botones, imagenes y modificar el texto a que se desea